# Visual Studio Solution Explorer does not show existing forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

[image]

I'm a Visual Studio - VB.NET User (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Versione 16.8.4) and after updating the IDE in my Solution Explorer the existing forms have disappeared (see img) from the list. If i .show() by code one form it open normally.

I tried to open a new project, import all and (after a while) same problem.

In Vini.vbproj:

```
<Compile Include="My Project\Agenti.Designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>Agenti.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="My Project\Agenti.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 1):

The files for that form are in the wrong folder. They shouldn't be in the *My Project* folder. They should be in the same folder as the other form(s). If you click the *Show All Files* button the *Solution Explorer* toolbar then you should be able to expand the *My Project* node and see that form. You can then drag and drop it to the root of the project.